# Depth first search tree edge classification

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I've got a basic question about DFS edge classification:  I have a directed graph with edges: 1->2, 2->3 and 1->3.  The edge classification for 1->2 is tree edge, 2->3 is tree edge.  I'm confused as to what the classification of 1->3 would be: forward edge, back edge or tree edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of edge classification (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search for example), 1->3 would be a forward edge.

This would be because:
1->2: tree edge because 2 is a descendant of 1 and 2 has not yet been discovered.
2->3: tree edge because 3 is a descendant of 2 and 3 has not yet been discovered.
1->3: forward edge because 3 is a descendant of 1 and has already been discovered.

3 is a descendant of 1 both directly and via 2.

Comment: just wanted to confirm, was confused due to something. Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not reflect the non-determinism of DFS. If the source is 1 and the first edge to be discovered is (1,3), it is a tree edge, not a forward edge, in which case (1,2) would also be a tree edge, while (2,3) would be a forward edge.

Comment: @G.Bach +1 Fair cop, guvnor.  I was assuming that the order that nodes were visited was the order the OP listed them in.  My answer could have been more complete.  Ta.